# Using Apache Camel REST DSL how to return different representation of a ressource depending of the HTTP Accept header

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I'm trying to use the Apache Camel REST DSL in order to return a different representation (xml, html, pdf) of a ressource using the HTTP Accept header.

Here is the current state of my code which is always returning the pdf representation either the client is sending Accept: text/html, application/xml or application/pdf.

```
    rest("/bpcg").description("BPCG rest service")
        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)

        .get("/{id}").description("Find BPCG by id").outType(String.class)
            .produces("application/xml")
                .param().name("id").type(path).description("The id of the BPCG to get").dataType("int").endParam()
                .to("bean:bpcgService?method=getBPCG(${header.id})")
            .produces("text/html")
                .param().name("id").type(path).dataType("int").endParam()
                .route()
                    .to("bean:bpcgService?method=getBPCG(${header.id})")
                    .to("xslt:com/connectivia/cie/spec/xslt/CIE - Business partner companion guide to HTML for Confluence.xsl")
                    .endRest()
            .produces("application/pdf")
                .param().name("id").type(path).dataType("int").endParam()
                .route().to("bean:bpcgService?method=getBPCG(${header.id})")
                    .to("xslt:com/connectivia/cie/spec/xslt/CIE - Business partner companion guide to PDF.xsl")
                    .to("xslt:com/connectivia/cie/spec/xslt/CIE - PDF Style Applier.xsl")
                    .to("bean:converter?method=ConvertXmlFoToPDF(${body})")
                    .endRest()
```